Springboot Pulsar ObjectMapper
We are using Spring pulsar (with SpringBoot) to create and consume JSON messages in Kotlin. However, to better support Kotlin+Json we need to create a custom ObjectMapper. Is it possible to force Spring Pulsar library to use a custom ObjectMapper?
Based on my research this is only possible if the underlying pulsar library used is not the "shaded" version which spring pulsar uses. But I'm not entirely sure how all of this fits together since SpringPulsar does some of the message parsing as well

Thanks for the report @gootik,
This is currently either impossible or very difficult. I have created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-pulsar/issues/723 to add this feature.
